# IntentService to start intent or broadcast message?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, geofencing

I currently have an intent service that is managing my geofence transitions and I am hoping to use the geofence ID to trigger a sequence of events either by starting an activity through another intent or by broadcasting the relevant string to my main activity so that I can do the process there. currently my code inside my intentservice contains this

```
    String fenceID = fences.get(0).getRequestId();
    Log.i( fenceID, "fenceID is");

    if (fenceID == Home){
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(PlayerActivity.MyWebRequestReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(fenceID, fenceID);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(RESPONSE_MESSAGE, "respone");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

  /*      Intent mpdIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class)
                .setData(Uri.parse("http://maxmarshall.ddns.net/segments/TEST_dash.mpd"))
                .putExtra(PlayerActivity.CONTENT_ID_EXTRA, "my test")
                .putExtra(PlayerActivity.CONTENT_TYPE_EXTRA, 0);
        startActivity(mpdIntent);*/
    }
```

You can see the commented out code is my original idea or end goal (whether it is completed through this set up or in another activity

However even though fenceID is Home I am not getting any response to that effect with this setup. Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong here? I can update the question with more code if anyone needs. perhaps I am not registering my broadcast receiver properly if theres something I need to put in the manifest? anyway thanks very much for any and all help!

Comment: Can you put a print statement like Log.i("Starting activity") right above your commented code and uncomment your code? It looks good, and I want to make sure your code is going through the if block.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't going through at this stage, this method helped me figure that out.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot start a new `Activity` from a `Service` context in the same task. The only way you can start an `Activity` from there is to use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Make sure you really need it before you implement this.

Your code for sending a broadcast message looks fine. Just make sure you register your receiver properly and it's `IntentFilter` matches.

Also, never do this:

```
String fenceID = fences.get(0).getRequestId();
Log.i( fenceID, "fenceID is");

if (fenceID == Home){
```

The `fenceId` is a `String`, i.e. it is a an `Object`. Comparing with `==` will give you `true` only if both references point to the same object. Is this really what you want in this case? Use `fenceId.equals(Home)` if you want to compare characters instead of objects.

My guess is that your code is never executed because of this mistake in the condition.